# After using trigger auto increment column is not sequential

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have this code that creates tables Nf0 and NF1 and updates NF1 it because of trigger NF1 if there are inserted values in NF0, but after inserting values in NF0 auto increment in NF1 is not sequential instead of 1,2,3,4 it is 1,2,4,5.

Can someone please tell me away how to get Ner column to be sequential automatically using trigger?

```
 drop database tron;
 create database tron;
 use tron;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TRON`.`NF0` (
`Numurs` varchar(45) ,
`Speletajs` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`DzimsanasDatums` date,
`Vecums` int(8) NOT NULL,
`Valsts` VARCHAR(45) not NULL,
`ValstsKods` VARCHAR(45) not NULL,
`AugumsCollas` varchar(45) not NULL,
`SvarsMarcinas` varchar(45) not null,
`Pozicija` text ,
`Klubs` varchar(45) not null,
`NospeletasSpeles` varchar(45) not null,
`PunktiAtlecosasPiespeles` text not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Speletajs,Klubs))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

create table if not exists TRON.numbers
AS  SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
SELECT 15  UNION ALL SELECT 16  UNION ALL SELECT 17  UNION ALL
SELECT 18   UNION ALL SELECT 19  UNION ALL SELECT 20;

create table if not exists TRON.NF1 like NF0;
alter table NF1
drop Speletajs,
drop Klubs,
drop PunktiAtlecosasPiespeles,
    add Vards varchar(45) not null after Numurs,
    add Uzvards varchar(45) not null after Vards,
    add RegionsPilseta varchar(45) not null after SvarsMarcinas,
    add Simbols varchar(45) not null after RegionsPilseta,
    add Punkti varchar(45) not null ,
    add Atlecosas varchar(45) , 
    add Piespeles varchar(45) ,
    add Ner int not null primary key auto_increment first;
 UPDATE `nf1` SET Vecums = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-   TO_DAYS(`DzimsanasDatums`)), '%Y' )+0;

 delimiter $
 CREATE TRIGGER `NF1` after insert 
ON `NF0` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERt INTO nf1 (
Ner,    
Numurs,
Vards,
Uzvards, 
DzimsanasDatums, 
Vecums, 
Valsts, 
ValstsKods, 
AugumsCollas, 
SvarsMarcinas, 
RegionsPilseta,
Simbols, 
Pozicija,
NospeletasSpeles,
Punkti,
Atlecosas,
Piespeles)
SELECT
'0',
'',
'',
'',
new.DzimsanasDatums as DzimsanasDatums,
new.Vecums as Vecums,
new.Valsts as Valsts,
new.ValstsKods as ValstsKods,
new.AugumsCollas as AugumsCollas,
new. SvarsMarcinas as SvarsMarcinas,
'',

'',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.Pozicija,' ',n),' ',-1) as Pozicija,
'',
'',
'',
''
FROM numbers n
WHERE LENGTH(NEW.Numurs) - LENGTH(REPLACE(NEW.Numurs,' ','')) >= n.n-1;
UPDATE `nf1` SET Vecums = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(`DzimsanasDatums`)), '%Y' )+0;

  end$$

 delimiter ;

 use TRON;
 insert into nf0 values ('23 6','LeBron James', '1984:12:30','31','United   States of America','USA',   '80','  250','  SF PF','    Cleveland Cavaliers,Miami Heat','   76 79', '25.3 7.4 6.8 26.7 7.5 7'),
                    ('23 6','Bron James',   '1984:12:30','31','United States of America','USA', '80','  250','  SF PF','    Cleveland Cavaliers,Miami Heat','   76 79', '25.3 7.4 6.8 26.7 7.5 7');


 select * from nf1;
```

Comment: In general, if you care about the numeric *values* of such a column, you're using it wrong. Ideally, they should be treated as opaque blobs that a) allow you to locate individual rows and b) happen to fit in numeric columns. Nothing else. Certainly not anything the users will see and so what should it matter what actual values are assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to duplicate your data (already a suspect idea) then do it in the business layer of your application rather than burying it in a trigger where it will be forgotten.

Once that logic is in your business layer you can determine the numeric value of your column however you need to (just get rid of the `auto_increment` property). `auto_increment` does not guarantee sequential numbers and was never intended to do so.